# ImageShader image size is too large

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to change the shape of an image using ImageShader.

I am getting the image with `_loadUiImage()` below.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

  Future<ui.Image> _loadUiImage(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(response.bodyBytes, completer.complete);
    return completer.future;
  }
```

It then displays the acquired image in its own form.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: loadUiImage("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/peak-bamboo-lijiang-rural-mist_1417-410.jpg"),
    builder: ((context, snapshot) => ShaderMask(
        blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
        shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
            ImageShader(snapshot.data!, TileMode.clamp, TileMode.clamp, Matrix4.identity().storage),
            child: _hoge, // some widget
));
```

However, the size of the image is too large compared to the size of the filter, like below.

[image]

I want the image to be smaller like the image below instead of like the one above.

[image]

Comment: seems that you need a scaled down matrix and not `Matrix4.identity()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink commented, The problem was `Matrix4.identity()`.
I replaced it to `Matrix4.diagonal3Values(x, y, z)` then this was solved.

Thank you pskink!